# Need help to decode an executable

Tags: c++, installation, installshield, installanywhere

I have a setup file `setupaix.bin` for an application X.
It is packaged with Install shield package technology from flexerasoftware.com. When I install the application X using this setup file, it stores the "X" productname, version and publisher in an xml file.  From this xml file, our parent inventory agent application will extract product name, version and publisher. But, my requirement is with out installing application X using the binary `setupaix.bin`.
Is there a way to decode this binary and extract the same product name, version and publisher information?

Please help me.
I have been searching for the answer for the past two months and I could get nothing out of any website.

Regards,

Sriram

Comment: So… when you're working on this for two months, have you actually contacted the company and asked them?

Comment: Yes Dark,<br>
I have posted it in flexera community blog and no body has responded till now.I have contact Install Shield support team as well.They just know how to package a software,but they don't know how to decode it.
<br>
Sriram